# Circular Dependency of classes

Tags: c++

hello guys i have a question about my little project when i try to compile code bellow i get error that one of my classes cant see other please help me! I think that I need some little fix to run this.
thanks.

```
#ifndef CLIENT_H_
#define CLIENT_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Message.h"
#include "Server.h"


class Client
{
private:
    Server* server;
    string name;
    vector<Message*> Messages;
public:
    Client(string _name, Server* _server);
    void printAllMessages();
    void printUnreadedMessages();
    bool sendMessage(string, string);
    void reciveMessage(Message*);
    string getName();
};

#endif



#ifndef SERVER_H_
#define SERVER_H_

#include "Client.h"
#include "Message.h"
#include <string>
#include <map>


class Server
{
private:
    map<string,Client*> clients;
    bool checkIfClientExist(string name);
public:
    Server();
    bool sendMessage(string,Message*);
    void addClient(Client* toBeAdded);
    void printAllClients();
};

#endif
```

In file included from Client.h:8:0, from Client.cpp:1: Server.h:13:13: error: ‘Client’ was not declared in this scope map clients; this is the full error code

Comment: In file included from Client.h:8:0,
                 from Client.cpp:1:
Server.h:13:13: error: ‘Client’ was not declared in this scope
  map<string,Client*> clients;

this is the full error code

Comment: You have a circular dependency. Client includes server that includes client that includes server that ....

Answer (score 4):

You have a circular dependency between your two header files. `Client.h` includes `Server.h`, and `Server.h` includes `Client.h`. As `Client.h` is being expanded, it defines its include guard `CLIENT_H_`, and then (eventually) tries to expand `Server.h`, which tries to include `Client.h` a second time. The include guard blocks it, because it's already defined, so `class Client` never actually gets defined prior to the `Server.h` code being parsed.

The solution here is to forward-declare `Client` as follows:

```
class Client;
```

You can put that line inside `Server.h`, or in `Client.h` above the include guard.

Comment: With the knowledge that you can only refer to `Client *` (not any methods or members) in the header file and save all real usage for the implementation CPP file.